Grand total row not updating when page size is changed
I have a grid with options
grandTotalRow: "bottom"
and multiple column with   aggFunc: 'sum'
I also have pagination set up for said grid
paginationPageSize: 25,
paginationPageSizeSelector: [10, 25, 50],

My problem is that changing the page size, don't update the grandTotalRow count
I have 17 rows and wathever the page size I choose, the grandTotalRow stay 17 with all the sum of the 17 rows, but with only the rows of the pagination visible.
If I had 200 rows it would show 200 in the grandTotalRow.
Anyone had any luck with grandTotalRow to only show paginated row? By the way it work properly with filtering.
